# Assign different label for each line in line graph for each iteration in js

Tags: javascript, loops, graph, chart.js

I am trying to plot a line graph using Chart.js library, where data is assigned through iterating loop. I am not able to assign different labels for each line in the line graph, The label is always assigned as the first indexed value of a loop in which I am iterating. Can anyone help me to solve this

Code:

```
        var channel = ["1", "10", "14", "110", "32", "7"];

        for (i=0; i < (channel.length); i++) {


                dataset.push({
                        data: datapush,
                        label:channel[i],
                        borderColor: "#FF0000",
                        backgroundColor:"red",
                        borderWidth:"01",
                        pointRadius:"0",
                        fill: false,


                    });

        }



        function drawGraph()
        {

            Chart.defaults.global.layout ="";
            Chart.defaults.global.legend.display =false;
            Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.tension=0.2,

            new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {

              type: 'line',

              data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets : dataset


              },
              options: {

                title: {
                  display: true,

                  text: 'Signal Strength'
                }
              }
            });

            }
```

you can refer this link for complete code:
https://github.com/chandupatilgithub/DM/blob/master/FinalGraph.html

Comment: Can you share the missing parts of the code too? I mean ```datapush```,```dataset```, ```labels```, etc

Comment: Can you please refer this link for the code: https://github.com/chandupatilgithub/DM/blob/master/FinalGraph.html